# unity prefab resizes prefab in game mode when in another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale

i've been having this problem with my 2d sprites (enemies characters in my case) where if I have a prefab already made from one scene that works just fine, and use that prefab in another scene, the size is not the same, but it behaves the same if it runs into a wall or something (it turns the other direction). It's not the script because the movement script is attached to other gameobjects that as of now behave the same way and those prefabs get imported to other scenes just fine. Does anyone know if this is a Unity bug or something? It's not a script issue I'm sure. In fact I know it isn't because it's happened with other enemies with different scripts. Sometimes this issue only happens in one scene, sometimes several, sometimes all of them, as long as it's not the original scene the game object and prefab was created in.

I should also mention that when I build the actual game, the game objects work as they should. It's only when I'm in the unity program itself that this is happening. But I can't properly test some scenes unless I were to build the game scene over and over which would be very counterproductive.

here's the script attached to the enemy for those insistent.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class foeHP : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject deathFlamePrefab;
Rigidbody2D erb;
public float Walk= 2.5f;
private float idle = 0f;
public float move = 2.5f;
public float hp = 3f;
private slicer slicy;
Animator anim;
private bool alive = true;
private bool damager = false;
private float invuln = 0f;
private bool nothurt = true;
public float wallCheckRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsWall;
private bool wallHit;
private bool goRight;
private bool atEdge = false;

public bool spotted;
public float xScale;
public float yScale;


public Transform wallCheck;

public Transform edgeCheck;
public GameObject bonePrefab;
public Transform boneSpawn;
public float fireDelay = 0.5f;
public float coolDownTimer = 0f;
public float timer3 = 0.75f;
private bool damagePlayed = false;


void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    erb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();


}

void Update ()
{

    invuln -= Time.deltaTime;
    Recover ();
    HandleMovement ();
    notHurting ();
//      Born ();
    damagePlayed = false;
}
public void takeDamage (float amount)
{
    hp -= amount;
    damager = true;



    if (!damagePlayed && alive && hp <= 0) 
    {

        Instantiate (deathFlamePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation); 
        Destroy (gameObject); 

    } 
    if (alive && hp > 0) {
        anim.SetTrigger ("damaged");
        invuln = 0.5f;
        gameObject.layer = 14;
        Invoke ("layerReturn", timer3);
    }
    if (alive && hp > 0 && !damagePlayed) {
            soundManager.PlaySFX ("enemyHit");
            damagePlayed = true;
    }
}

void layerReturn()
{
    gameObject.layer = 12;
}

public void HandleMovement()
{
    if (wallCheck == null) {
        return;
    } else {

    wallHit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (wallCheck.position, wallCheckRadius, whatIsWall);
    atEdge = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (edgeCheck.position, wallCheckRadius, whatIsWall);


        if (wallHit || !atEdge)
            goRight = !goRight;

        if (goRight) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-xScale, yScale, 1f);
            erb.velocity = new Vector2 (move, erb.velocity.y);
            anim.SetFloat ("walk", Mathf.Abs (move));
        } else {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (xScale, yScale, 1f);
            erb.velocity = new Vector2 (-move, erb.velocity.y);
            anim.SetFloat ("walk", Mathf.Abs (move));

        }
    }

    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (12, 12);
}

public void Recover ()
{
    if (invuln <= 0)
        gameObject.layer = 12;
    nothurt = false;


    if (invuln <= 0)
        anim.SetLayerWeight (1, 0);
    nothurt = true;
}


public void notHurting()
{
    if (invuln > 0)
        erb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        spotted = true;
    else
        spotted = false;

}


/*  void Born ()
{
    coolDownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;


    if (spotted && coolDownTimer <= 0) 
    {


        coolDownTimer = fireDelay;

        anim.SetTrigger ("Throw");
        Instantiate (bonePrefab, boneSpawn.position, boneSpawn.rotation);

        if (!spotted)
            fireDelay = 0;  
    }   
}
*/
}
```

Comment: Does your gameobject have a different parent in the other scene?

Comment: it does not : /

Comment: Can you try replacing transform.localscale with transform.scale and see if anything changes? Also can you test the scene by commenting out the physics2d.ignorelayercollision?

Comment: To add to my previous comment. You should really remove ignore collision from your update method, because ignore collision resets your trigger state. Having it in your update method means your triggerstate is reset every frame which can cause a lot of weird behaviour. Either set it in your start/ awake or even better: use the built in collision matrix

Comment: k i'll test these things out. thanks for the feedback :)